# Do I actually get more points for finishing the map quicker in Age of Wonders?

Tags: age-of-wonders

Many guides for Age of Wonders, the 1999 game, claim that you get more points if you finish the maps quickly and get penalized for delaying the end. Is that actually true? I haven't noticed that, but that's probably because it typically takes a lot of time for me to win.